# How to read EMF file in .NET?

Tags: .net, parsing, printing, printers, .emf

I would like to read the content of an EMF spool file into a .NET application and extract the text content. Can anyone help suggest an approach for doing this? Any libraries or objects available off-the-shelf? Or any suggestions on a EMF file parsing example?

Comment: @IanT8: The .emf tag explains what it is.  So does your favorite search engine.

Comment: I would be surprised if there are off-the-shelf .NET components available for decoding spool files, and a quick search turns up nothing.  Decoding spool files is kind of a decidedly C++ thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with rendering it and then using the result, there's Imageresizing.net that can render EMFs for you and give you a PNG for example based on it. That way you could for example render it in a browser to create some kind of viewer thing - which would be slow as all hell but still.

Then there's www.MetaDraw.com as well but I haven't actually used it - might be better or worse.